# issue with abstract classes and inheritence

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

suppose I have those 2 classes:

```
class num{
public:
    int a;
    num(){};
    num(int x):a(x){};
    num(const num& n):a(n.a){}
    virtual bool operator==(const num& n)const = 0;
    virtual ~num(){};
};

class tmp: public num{
public:
    tmp(){};
    tmp(int x):num(x){};
    tmp(const num& n): num(n){}
    tmp(const tmp& t): num(t.a){}
    virtual bool operator==(const num& n)const{
        return tmp(n).a == a;
    }
    virtual ~tmp(){};
};
```

and something like this in main:

```
int main() {
    num* x = &get(...);

    return 0;
}
```

`get` return a reference of type `tmp` (in this case. in general it returns reference to a type that inherits from `num`)
what I want to do is create another `num* y` that will point to a **copy** of `*x` so that if I change `*y` I won't change `*x`. and I can't quite figure out how to do this since `num` is abstract so I can't create an object of this type to make a copy.

ok and another question. 
if I overload `<<` operator:

```
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const tmp& t){
        return os<<t.a<<endl;
    }
```

and then try to do this:

```
cout<<*x<<endl;
```

I get an error `no match for 'operator<<'`
why is that?

Comment: Just use `tmp`'s copy constructor ?

Comment: I'm using `num*` because I don't know what `get` returns. it can be `tmp` or some other type that inherits from `num`. so i can't use a specific copy constructor

Comment: Of course. Brain hiccup.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [*prototype pattern*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns/Creational_Patterns#Prototype), also often called *clone pattern*.

It's basically a pure virtual method

```
virtual std::unique_ptr<num> clone() const = 0;
```

... that you declare in `num`, to be overriden by each derived class. You then just call `x->clone();` to get a brand new object of the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a virtual function to clone an object based on its dynamic type. It will have to return a (preferably smart) pointer to a newly allocated object of the correct type. For example:

```
class num {
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<num> clone() const = 0;
    // other members...
};

class my_num : public num {
public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<num> clone() const {
        return std::make_unique<my_num>(*this);
    }
    // other members...
};

int main() {
    num* x = &get(...);
    auto y = x->clone();
}
```